# Ampps selected PHP 5.6 by PHP -v says it's got PHP 5.5

Tags: php, apache, localhost, ampps

I'm using a Mac and AMPPS ... I've selected to use PHP 5.6 and I have been able to install Magento 2 which has min requirements of PHP 5.6.
Magento 2 is installed and working fine.

Now, when I open my terminal and type: PHP -v

It says I'm using PHP 5.5.

Why could this be happening, any ideas?

Comment: What does `phpinfo` show when executed through apache? Maybe http://superuser.com/questions/971867/why-is-the-php-version-different-in-phpinfo-and-cli

Comment: Very interesting ... phpinfo says: PHP Version 5.6 although php -v is still says it's php 5.5 :o/

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 versions installed and the CLI is using the 5.5 one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. I was basically installing the php update but I also needed to set the path so he's the solution:

```
1. curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6

2. export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH

3. php -v
```

You'll now get version 5.6